# How to create collection view inside table view cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

How to create like this collection view with different cell size inside table view cell  and also inside collection view cell image need to download from url cell [image: How to create like this collection view with different cell size inside table view]

i tried below code, but last 2 small cells going up , and also when the image downloaded from url collection view is not loading until manually touch collection view

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let cVWidth = collectionView.frame.width
        let biggerCellWidth = (cVWidth / 2.5) - 5
        if indexPath.row == 2 || indexPath.row == 3 {
            let testValue:CGFloat = 3
            return CGSize(width: (biggerCellWidth / 2) - testValue  , height: (biggerCellWidth / 2) - testValue )
        }
        return CGSize(width: biggerCellWidth, height: biggerCellWidth)
    }
```

Comment: you should try something first.you can found lot of articles on internet

Comment: i added the code which tried,

Comment: but cell position of last 2 small cell not coming properly

Answer (score 0):

For creating a collection view inside a table view go to this [link](https://ashfurrow.com/blog/putting-a-uicollectionview-in-a-uitableviewcell-in-swift/)

There is a method in **UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout**

```
collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize
```

where you can set the size of collection view cell size. Say you want to set the third and fourth cell's height as half of the collection view and square in size. Put this condition

```
if indexPath.row == 2 || indexPath.row == 3
{
    let height = collectionView.bounds.size.height / 2
    return CGSize(width: height, height: height)
}
```